# Jquery code still working ignoring the condition

Tags: jquery, if-statement, window-resize

I'm trying to create a scroll function to my header and i wanted it to fire only when i'm above the 1280px and when i resize the screen i also wanted to works oonly above 1280px

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
           

             function checkWidth() {
                 if ($(window).width() >= 1280) {
                     $(document).ready(function () {
                         $(window).scroll(function () {
                             var height = $(window).scrollTop();
                             console.log(menuHeight)
                             if (height > 10) {
                                 $('#toggleNav').show(300).css({ 'display': 'flex' });
                                 $('#articleGroupMenu').hide(350)
                                 $('.sticky-wrapper,#headerContainer').css({ "height": "162", 'transition': 'all 0.3s linear' })


                             } else {
                                 $('#articleGroupMenu').show(350)
                                 $('#toggleNav').hide(300)
                                 $('.sticky-wrapper,#headerContainer').css({ "height": "191", 'transition': 'all 0.3s linear' })

                             }
                         });
                     });
                 }
             }  
             // Execute on load
             checkWidth();
             // Bind event listener
             $(window).resize(checkWidth);
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Every time you resize, you add a *new* / *additional* scroll handler, so the old scroll handlers are still there.  Move the `.scrol(function()` event binding outside of checkWidth and call checkWidth from both resize and scroll.  (also: the inner doc.ready, it doesn't nothing)

Comment: @freedomn-m thx, yes the problem was as u escribed, now it works as expected